# Releveling factor to facilitate use as nested factor in DESeq2 model in R

Tags: r, data.table, bioconductor

I am fitting a GLM using the DESeq2 package, and have the situation where individuals (RatIDs) are nested within the treatment (Diet). The author of the package suggests that the individuals be re-leveled from 1:N within each Diet (where N is the number of RatIDs within a specific Diet) rather than their original ID/factor level ([DESeq2 vignette, page 35](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.pdf).)

The data looks something like this (there are actually more columns and rows, but omitted for simplicity):

```
     Diet Extraction RatID
199 HAMSP          8    65
74   HAMS          9   108
308  HAMS         18   100
41  HAMSA          3    83
88  HAMSP         12    11
221 HAMSP         14    66
200 HAMSA          8    57
155 HAMSB          1   105
245 HAMSB         19    50
254  HAMS         21    90
182 HAMSB          4     4
283 HAMSA         23    59
180 HAMSP          4    22
71  HAMSP          9   112
212  HAMS         12    63
220 HAMSP         14    54
56   HAMS          7    81
274 HAMSP          1    11
114  HAMS         17   102
143 HAMSP         22    93
```

And here is a `dput()` output for the structure:

```
data = structure(list(Diet = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
        3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("HAMS", 
        "HAMSA", "HAMSB", "HAMSP", "LAMS"), class = "factor"), Extraction = c(8L, 
        9L, 18L, 3L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 19L, 21L, 4L, 23L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 
        14L, 7L, 1L, 17L, 22L), RatID = structure(c(61L, 7L, 3L, 76L, 
        9L, 62L, 52L, 6L, 46L, 81L, 37L, 54L, 20L, 12L, 59L, 50L, 74L, 
        9L, 4L, 84L), .Label = c("1", "10", "100", "102", "103", "105", 
        "108", "109", "11", "110", "111", "112", "113", "13", "14", "16", 
        "17", "18", "20", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
        "3", "30", "31", "32", "34", "35", "36", "37", "39", "4", "40", 
        "42", "43", "45", "46", "48", "49", "5", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
        "54", "55", "57", "58", "59", "6", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
        "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "73", "77", "78", "79", 
        "8", "80", "81", "82", "83", "85", "86", "88", "89", "90", "91", 
        "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "98", "99"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Diet", 
        "Extraction", "RatID"), row.names = c(199L, 74L, 308L, 41L, 88L, 
        221L, 200L, 155L, 245L, 254L, 182L, 283L, 180L, 71L, 212L, 220L, 
        56L, 274L, 114L, 143L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone please specify an elegant way to generate the new factor levels for RatIDs within Diet as an additional column of the above data.frame.
Could this be done with the roll function of data.table?

Desired output (done manually):

```
    Diet Extraction RatID newCol
1  HAMSP          8    65      1
2   HAMS          9   108      1
3   HAMS         18   100      2
4  HAMSA          3    83      1
5  HAMSP         12    11      2
6  HAMSP         14    66      3
7  HAMSA          8    57      2
8  HAMSB          1   105      1
9  HAMSB         19    50      2
10  HAMS         21    90      3
11 HAMSB          4     4      3
12 HAMSA         23    59      3
13 HAMSP          4    22      4
14 HAMSP          9   112      5
15  HAMS         12    63      4
16 HAMSP         14    54      6
17  HAMS          7    81      5
18 HAMSP          1    11      2
19  HAMS         17   102      6
20 HAMSP         22    93      7
```

NOTE: There are not an equal number of Rats in each treatment. I'd also like the solution to not re-order the rows in the data (if possible).

EDIT: There  is no 'natural' order to the RatIDs, just as long as there is a 1:1 mapping within a diet, its fine.

Comment: I would like the new ID to be from 1:N within each diet, but your suggestion gives 1:N across the diets. Will modify my question to emphasize that bit!

Comment: I didn't emphasize it, but there are multiple samples from the same rat (Rat 11 has two). When I run the above, Rat 11 gets two ids. The order of RatID does not have to be preserved when mapped to the new IDs.

Comment: You're right, human error there. Will fix.

Comment: I posted a modified solution and it seems to match with the expected output you showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the 'RatID' to 'factor' and coerce it back to 'numeric'

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
 setDT(data)[, newCol:=as.numeric(factor(RatID, 
                       levels=unique(RatID))), Diet]
 #      Diet Extraction RatID newCol
 # 1: HAMSP          8    65      1
 # 2:  HAMS          9   108      1
 # 3:  HAMS         18   100      2
 # 4: HAMSA          3    83      1
 # 5: HAMSP         12    11      2
 # 6: HAMSP         14    66      3
 # 7: HAMSA          8    57      2
 # 8: HAMSB          1   105      1
 # 9: HAMSB         19    50      2
 #10:  HAMS         21    90      3
 #11: HAMSB          4     4      3
 #12: HAMSA         23    59      3
 #13: HAMSP          4    22      4
 #14: HAMSP          9   112      5
 #15:  HAMS         12    63      4
 #16: HAMSP         14    54      6
 #17:  HAMS          7    81      5
 #18: HAMSP          1    11      2
 #19:  HAMS         17   102      6
 #20: HAMSP         22    93      7
```

Or use `match`

```
 setDT(data)[, newCol:=match(RatID, unique(RatID)), Diet]
```

Or similar option with `base R`

```
data$newCol <- with(data, ave(as.numeric(levels(RatID))[RatID],
       Diet, FUN=function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

Comment: You might find this confusing, but I only need to generate IDs for a subset of the time-points in my dataset. The IDs are generated correctly using the above, but I noticed that there are more levels in the factor than members                                                                                                  `qsd = data.table(qsd)
  setkey(qsd, Days)    
  
  ## only assign nested effects for rats within diet treatment, so time points 94,105,126,133
  qsd[c("94","105","126","133"), RatIDByDiet:= as.numeric(factor(RatID, levels=unique(RatID))), by=Diet]`

Comment: @Meep Sorry, I didn't get your comment.  Can you update the info in your post.

Comment: please ignore my previous comment! I think a downstream function was changing the levels of my factor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `as.numeric(factor(.))` trick implemented in `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Diet) %>% mutate(RatIDByDiet=as.numeric(factor(RatID)))
## Source: local data frame [20 x 4]
## Groups: Diet
## 
##     Diet Extraction RatID RatIDByDiet
## 1  HAMSP          8    65           5
## 2   HAMS          9   108           3
## 3   HAMS         18   100           1
## 4  HAMSA          3    83           3
## 5  HAMSP         12    11           1
## 6  HAMSP         14    66           6
## 7  HAMSA          8    57           1
## 8  HAMSB          1   105           1
## 9  HAMSB         19    50           3
## 10  HAMS         21    90           6
## 11 HAMSB          4     4           2
## 12 HAMSA         23    59           2
## 13 HAMSP          4    22           3
## 14 HAMSP          9   112           2
## 15  HAMS         12    63           4
## 16 HAMSP         14    54           4
## 17  HAMS          7    81           5
## 18 HAMSP          1    11           1
## 19  HAMS         17   102           2
## 20 HAMSP         22    93           7
```

And here is a solution that avoids going through `factor()`, if you want more control over how the numbering happens:

```
data %>% group_by(Diet) %>% mutate(RatIDByDiet=match(RatID, unique(RatID)))
## Source: local data frame [20 x 4]
## Groups: Diet
## 
##     Diet Extraction RatID RatIDByDiet
## 1  HAMSP          8    65           1
## 2   HAMS          9   108           1
## 3   HAMS         18   100           2
## 4  HAMSA          3    83           1
## 5  HAMSP         12    11           2
## 6  HAMSP         14    66           3
## 7  HAMSA          8    57           2
## 8  HAMSB          1   105           1
## 9  HAMSB         19    50           2
## 10  HAMS         21    90           3
## 11 HAMSB          4     4           3
## 12 HAMSA         23    59           3
## 13 HAMSP          4    22           4
## 14 HAMSP          9   112           5
## 15  HAMS         12    63           4
## 16 HAMSP         14    54           6
## 17  HAMS          7    81           5
## 18 HAMSP          1    11           2
## 19  HAMS         17   102           6
## 20 HAMSP         22    93           7
```

Comment: One issue I can see is that Rat 11 (has two samples, both same diet) , but gets assigned different IDs.

Comment: @Meep You're correct. Fixed. I'm still looking for an alternative way of doing this that doesn't require `as.numeric(factor())`, but have not been successful yet.

Comment: @Meep Solved it. Wasn't that hard after all. --- Ah, now I see that Akrun had that option already as well.

Comment: Nice to see a dplyr solution, haven't used that before!

Comment: I generally prefer dplyr to data.table, because dplyr code is usually easier to read. And easier to read = fewer bugs.